# How to disable image caching in Odoo email?

Tags: python, email, gmail, odoo, no-cache

I'm currently using   Odoo 12.0+e-20181025. I have changed the logo for the email but the GMail that has received the previous email refused to show the new logo although the link of the image in the email has pointed to the new logo.

I have checked the image and it is the correct image. I've also tried following the URL in the email that showed the previous (the wrong) image, and it led to a correct image, just not showing it in the email display.

I've read that it has something to do with the Gmail image caching function, but since most of my users are using Gmail, I need to make it so that the image won't cache and my idea at the moment is to add no-cache at the header HTML, but I don't know where can I set that in my current version of Odoo.

Thank you for reading and for your help.

Comment: Which template have you checked with?

Comment: The template for whenever a ticket from helpdesk had its stage changed from "New" to "Open".

Comment: Delete it and load or update the module

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found the answer. It is in the view > mail_notification_light

Here are the first few lines of codes in the XML

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<t t-name="mail.mail_notification_light">
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="padding-top: 16px; background-color: #F1F1F1; font-family:Verdana, Arial,sans-serif; color: #454748; width: 100%; border-collapse:separate;"><tr><td align="center">
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="590" style="padding: 24px; background-color: white; color: #454748; border-collapse:separate;">
```

Then changed into these.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<t t-name="mail.mail_notification_light">
<meta http-equiv="Cache-control" content="no-cache" />
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="padding-top: 16px; background-color: #F1F1F1; font-family:Verdana, Arial,sans-serif; color: #454748; width: 100%; border-collapse:separate;"><tr><td align="center">
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="590" style="padding: 24px; background-color: white; color: #454748; border-collapse:separate;">
```

So I put the  in there. So far, it works wonder. Once again, thank you for everyone that has been reading and giving comment.